# Ocaml change type 'a tree to 'b tree

Tags: ocaml

I have defined

```
type 'a tree =
| Tree of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
| Leaf of 'a
| Null;;
```

Now I have to define a function that will change the whole `'a tree` in to an `'b tree`.

I have searched on google and tried to solve it myself but I'm stucked. Any tips?

Comment: As a side remark, note that your tree type is a bit odd : you can have two different representation for a leaf  wich let's say contains the value 1. Either  ````Leaf(1) ```` or ````Tree(Null,1,Null)  ````. A more idiomatic binary tree type  - that avoids this redundancy - would be the following : ````type 'a tree = | Tree of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree | Leaf ````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possibility is an analog to the `map` function but over trees. For example:

```
let rec treemap f t = match t with
    Null           -> Null
 |  Leaf x         -> Leaf (f x)
 |  Tree (l, x, r) -> Tree (treemap f l, f x, treemap f r)
```

Here `t : 'a tree`, `f : 'a -> 'b`, and `treemap : 'a tree -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b tree`, which produces a `'b tree` as desired.

---

This is the most "natural" way of making such a function: you have a tree with values of type `'a`, and you want to get a new tree with values of type `'b` - so you just need a tree and some way of mapping a value of one type to a value of the other.

I think it's worth pointing out that this isn't the only such function. You could make a function `treereplace : 'a tree -> 'b -> 'b tree`, which just creates an identically structured tree but replacing every value with the one given, or a function which does the same but flips the left/right branches of each `Tree` node. There's an infinite number of functions taking an `'a tree` and producing a `'b tree` that you could make, the above is just arguably the most natural and useful.

Edit: Improvements/critique welcome - I don't know OCaml, I hacked this example together from an understanding of SML.

Comment: Looks good to me. You can drop the double semi-colon at the end (it's only useful in the repl) but apart from that it's pretty idiomatic.